# Put images in the media from url functions

Tags: functions, media

When the client installs my theme I would like to automatically download images and add them to the media library, e.g. from links like this:

https://images.pexels.com/photos/2228559/pexels-photo-2228559.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940

How would I do this? Do I need to use wp_insert_attachment  ?

Thanks

Comment: can you rephrase/reword your question? It doesn't make sense. Try to use multiple sentences rather than a single long sentence

Comment: I would like that when a person downloads my theme, this one (so the theme) has images already stored in the library (media).